# Why can I not edit a tag wiki on SFF?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I currently have over 3500 reputation, 1500 is the rep to accept an edit. I can even see that there is a pending wiki tag edit in the queue. But, I'm not allowed to approve it. Are all tag wiki entries. I'm the #2 answerer of the tag, with over 50 up votes, but I can't approve it... Doesn't quite make sense to me. What's going on? Thanks!

Comment: belongs on http://meta.sff?

Comment: tag wiki on main site or meta site?

Comment: and you mean tag wiki edit approve right? not tag synonyms approve?

Comment: @YOU: Tag wiki on the main site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be allowed to submit edits to any tag wiki, unless there is an edit in the pipeline. When you reach 4000 rep (as this is site is in public beta) you will become a trusted user and be able to edit wikis without waiting for approval.

- You may not approve your own edits to tag wikis ...
- You may not vote any more on tag wiki edits if you pass the threshold of 30 votes per day ...

Comment: So, I can approve other people's (Which only requires 1500), but I don't have full rights to edit them myself? Just making sure I understand this...

Comment: You can edit them as soon as they are approved in transit ones can not

Comment: Are the edits of a tag's top users supposed to be shoved into the suggested edit queue?

Comment: @Tim yeah ... but once they get 20k the queue is bypassed... the per tag rules were just too complex

Comment: Hmm...I don't disagree, but it seems kind of weird that I can edit anyone's post, even in tags I have no experience in, yet I can't edit the tag wiki (that I wrote in the first place) of a tag I'm the second-ranked answerer in without getting approval from other users.

Comment: well @Tim the trouble is that wikis have really high visibility now (with the new tag editor and all) ... we need to be extra careful