# Typo in "create tag wiki" placeholder

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki

It seems to me like the stated number might be incorrect:

> (Note that if you have less than 20000 reputation, your tag wiki will be peer reviewed before it is published.)

Comment: That's not a typo. Being able to edit tag wiki without peer review is a [20k privilege](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You *do* [need 20,000 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) to edit a tag wiki without your edit being put into the review queue. The text is correct.

[waffles justifies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89635/why-can-i-not-edit-a-tag-wiki-on-sff/89662#comment258896_89662) this requirement by explaining that because of the high visibility that tag wikis are supposed to have, it's better to be safe than sorry when people make edits to them.

Comment: Oops. I was looking at the wrong page. My mistake, sorry!