# Number formatting when editing tag wiki with less than 20000 reputation

Tags: feature-request, tags, reputation, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

When editing a tag wiki, the following box is displayed.

Can a comma be added so this reads `20,000 reputation` instead of `20000 reputation`?

[image]

**Note**: whatever separator is being used on the [privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) page would be just fine.

*[It seems that others have also misread this as two-thousand, instead of twenty-thousand.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123470/typo-in-create-tag-wiki-placeholder)*